# Use Resource Files In ASP.NET for HTML controls

Tags: asp.net, html

is it possible to use resource files (.resx) in ASP.NET for a HTML controls ?

Comment: How do you mean? Can you post an example of what you would like to do?

Comment: for ASP controls I assign meta:resourcekey="CompanyNameTb", but is it possible to do the same with a HTML tag, e.g. <a></a> ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You neeed to add runat="server" to the control.

```
<input type="button" value="Press Me" runat="server" 
   meta:resourcekey="PressMeButtonResources"/>
```

Alternatively, you could retrieve resource values programmatically. Here is a an [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227982%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) on how to do that. Then you could generate content on the Server side and apply it to your page.

Comment: is it possible without adding runat="server" to page?